# message is shown twice before unload happens

Tags: javascript, html

I want to give a message to user before page is unloaded . My page is in a  iframe and there are sidemenu int the page which on clicking load another iframe. I have written this code

```
window.onbeforeunload = function()
{  
 return 'Any unsaved changes will be lost';
}
```

the problem is that on clicking ok button this message is given again, and then again pressing ok it navigate to other page. How to avoid this

Comment: put this code not in the iframe code... put it in the container of the iframes.

Comment: Use `window.top.onbeforeunload` instead of `window.onbeforeunload`